# Why a select query trigger optimistic locking error in JPA hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, optimistic-locking

There is one ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException thrown. I check the log and find this exception is triggered by a select query. This is werid.

Here is the exception stack trace.

```
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:317)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:491)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy117.countOtherRoles(Unknown Source)
    at net.homecredit.mcd.app.service.UserRolePosService.countOtherRoles(UserRolePosService.java:315)
    at net.homecredit.mcd.app.service.UserRolePosService.canRemoveEmployer(UserRolePosService.java:375)
    at net.homecredit.mcd.app.service.UserRolePosService.deactivate(UserRolePosService.java:339)
    at net.homecredit.mcd.app.service.UserRolePosService.fillRoleData(UserRolePosService.java:241)
    at net.homecredit.mcd.app.service.UserRolePosService.fillRoleData(UserRolePosService.java:199)
    at net.homecredit.mcd.app.service.UserRolePosService.fillRoleData(UserRolePosService.java:180)
    at net.homecredit.mcd.app.service.pos.PosBusinessService.saveUserRole(PosBusinessService.java:224)
    at net.homecredit.mcd.app.service.pos.PosBusinessService.updatePos(PosBusinessService.java:121)
    at net.homecredit.mcd.app.service.pos.PosBusinessService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ad825d06.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:721)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:69)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at net.homecredit.mcd.common.security.ForbiddingSecurityInterceptor.invoke(ForbiddingSecurityInterceptor.java:17)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at net.homecredit.mcd.common.aop.AuditInterceptor.invoke(AuditInterceptor.java:21)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:656)
    at net.homecredit.mcd.app.service.pos.PosBusinessService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7cfba5de.updatePos(<generated>)
    at net.homecredit.mcd.app.service.homesis.kafka.HsisKafkaConsumer.updatePos(HsisKafkaConsumer.java:122)
    at net.homecredit.mcd.app.service.homesis.kafka.HsisKafkaConsumer.updatePos(HsisKafkaConsumer.java:97)
    at net.homecredit.mcd.app.service.homesis.kafka.HsisKafkaConsumer.consumePos(HsisKafkaConsumer.java:73)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor871.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:180)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:112)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.HandlerAdapter.invoke(HandlerAdapter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:174)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:82)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:975)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeWithRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:959)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:901)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:786)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:656)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) : [net.homecredit.mcd.app.domain.Pos#2307536273]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.check(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2400)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3202)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3077)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3457)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:589)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:463)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.autoFlushIfRequired(SessionImpl.java:1398)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1483)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1445)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1414)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1463)
    at net.homecredit.mcd.app.dao.UserRolePosDao.countOtherRoles(UserRolePosDao.java:225)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    ... 47 common frames omitted
```

The log shows it encounters a optimistic lock error while updating the POS table.  This line
`"at net.homecredit.mcd.app.dao.UserRolePosDao.countOtherRoles(UserRolePosDao.java:225)"`, triggers this optimistic error. I check this code.

```
    public Integer countOtherRoles(User user, UserRolePos userRole) {
        return em.createNamedQuery(UserRolePos.COUNT_OTHER_ROLE_FOR_USER, Long.class)
                .setParameter("user", user)
                .setParameter("userRole", userRole)
                .getSingleResult().intValue();
    }
```

Related query is as below

```
 @NamedQuery(name = UserRolePos.COUNT_OTHER_ROLE_FOR_USER,
        query = "SELECT COUNT(urp) FROM UserRolePos urp " +
                "WHERE urp.user = :user " +
                "AND urp != :userRole "
        )
```

It is just a select query with another UserRole table, why this trigger the optimistic lock error with POS table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look closely in the stacktrace, you will notice that Hibernate does "auto-flushing". This happens when you have "dirty" entities in your persistence context and try to do a query that uses tables, which intersect with the tables of the dirty entities. If it wouldn't flush the dirty entries, you might get wrong results.

Comment: Thanks, I guess there is one "dirty" POS entity in the context. But how does hibernate konw that this is a dirty entity? It compares the versions between entity and table rows in the background?

Comment: When Hibernate loads the entity, it remembers the state. Since the entity is associated with the persistence context, it will check if it is dirty. So essentially, yes, Hibernate does compare that in the background, but it doesn't do that by issuing a separate query.